# C++ Code outputs two characters when I only desire one output (Fix found!) <3

Tags: c++, output

As simple as it sounds. I'm a newb when it comes to c++, but I have been following cpp reference and some online tutorials to write code. My code should output a string as "SuCh", but instead it outputs something as "SSuuCChh". Is there a practical error I'm missing?

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string mani;
    int L = 0;
    getline(cin, mani);
    for (int i = 0; i<mani.length();i++){
        if(mani.at(i) == ' '){
            cout << ' ' << flush;
            L = L - 2;
        } else if(L%2==0){
            putchar(toupper(mani.at(i)));
            L++;
        } else if(L%1==0) {
            putchar(tolower(mani.at(i)));
            L++;
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i%1 == 0` is always true.

Comment: Tip: Don't write inverse conditions with `else if` if the only remaining possibility is the opposite of the first. Just use `else` to avoid tripping yourself up. In this case, `i % 2` is going to be `1` or `0`, nothing else.

Comment: Is that true? Greg Hewgill's answer works for what I need, and does return i%2==0 when I need it to as well. The only issue I have now is space detection, but I'm sure that'll be an easy fix.

Comment: @tadman I apologize if you think that comment is directed towards you; As for the if else, I'm going to add a third option that detects if the location is a space and decide to just cout a space without messing up the line

Comment: Fair enough. Just an observation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `putchar` *and* using `cout`, so you're printing each character twice in two different ways.

Eliminate either the call to `putchar()`, or the `cout <<`, and you will only get each character once.

Comment: I'm so glad it was an easy fix like that , for some reason I assumed putchar only changed the value but never actually output it

I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me!

Comment: You will not find any C++ textbook that says anything useful about `putchar`, which is a C library function, used in C code only. `putchar`, here, can possibly make an appearance solely due to its presence in search engine results. A search engine is not a very good C++ textbook.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: [`std::putchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/putchar) is a C++ standard library function too. Essentially all C library functions are also available in C++, even if they are not commonly used or not recommended or not generally accepted C++ style.

Answer (score 0):

From [cplusplus's putchar(int) reference](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/putchar/):

> int putchar ( int character );
> Write character to stdout.

> It is equivalent to calling putc with stdout as second argument.

So your code should look more like

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
    std::string mani, F;
    getline(std::cin, mani);

    for(int i = 0; i < mani.length; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) { 
            std::cout << std::toupper(mani.at(i));
        } else {
            std::cout << std::tolower(mani.at(i));
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Extra includes of  and  are there to ensure those types are included. They may be able to be removed, however I would leave them. Plus, dropping the std prefix can be dangerous due to certain popular libraries, such as Boost, defining their own versions of the functions and objects.